# P2P передача данных по UDP

Tags: c++, c, сеть, p2p

подскажите точку старта. Задача: устройство IoT с выходом в инет, сервер с выходом в инет, белых IP нет, наобходимо данные по UDP отправлять на сервер. VPN не подходит, т.к. для Iot устройства нет VPN клиента. Прочитал про технолгию P2P, которая может решить проблему. НО, как реализовать практически? Я так понимаю, что нужен какой то внешний сервер, который получит ID устройства и сервера и соединит их? Как отдельный сервер выполнит соединение? Как такового, P2P протокола нет, а что брать за основу тогда? В общем нужна консультация по этому вопросу. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если Ваше устройство и сервер находятся в **одной** локалке, то зачем Вам иНет ?! Пусть связываются напрямую.

Comment: Устройство и сервер в разных сетях на разных краях земли.

Comment: А нет возможности дать белый IP серверу, это бы кардинально решило проблему. И кстати, как вообще вы собираетесь устанавливать связь если IP нет ни у одной стороны. Пройти NAT во многих случаях можно, но как устройства вообще будут искать сервер если его адрес не известен. Нужна тогда еще какая то служба определения адресов, при этом все равно присутствующая в интернете на постоянном адресе

Comment: Есть [это](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)), но выглядит ненадежно.

Comment: Используя P2P работают китайские камеры. в приложении вводите ID камеры, далее китайский сервак соединяет камеру и приложение, при этом данные не идут через сервер. Мне требуется подобная система.

Comment: Звучит так буд-то ты ищешь UDP Hole Punching… но для этого нужен хотя бы один сервер с белым IP…

Comment: да, что то похожее ищу, но UDP hole не всегда возможно пробить. Насчет промежуточного сервера с белым IP, это не проблема, только устройство и сервер приложения не имет реал IP и за NaTом находятся.

Answer (score 0):

> - данные ... отправлять на сервер
> - белых IP нет

Пишите письма! :-) Ну, это - просто идея. Нужно какое-то место в иНете, в которое доступ имеют оба устройства. Тогда одно устройство складывает туда данные, а другое - забирает. Почто - это один из вариантов. Но их много разных.

Comment: нужна потоковая передача данных в реальном времени с минимальной задержкой.

Comment: @ArthurShydlovskyi Без статического IP всё равно не обойтись. Существуют технологии реализации P2P через промежуточный сервер с общим доступом. Посмотрите аот это: https://cyberinfa.com/chto-takoe-odnorangovaya-set-p2p-chto-takoe-torrent/